# How to show a simply-connected negatively-curved n-dimensional Riemannian manifold is homeomorphic to $R^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I saw this word in a paper , but there is not proof . And a simple hint is given that for fixing a poing $0\in M$ , mapping the $T_0M$ noto $M$ via exponential map. But it is not enough to say it is homeomorphic . How to show it ?

Comment: This is called the Cartan-Hadamard Theorem, and you can find its statement and proof in virtually every book on Riemannian geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homeomorphism is given by mapping point $rv \in T_0M$, where $ r \in \Bbb R^{+}$ and $\|v\| = 1$, to the point to $\exp_0(rv) \in M$.

You still have to show that this map is injective, but that's what the negative curvature is for: you use it to estimate the distance to the nearest "focal point" of $\exp$, which turns out to be infinitely far away.

Comment: could you give a detail conference ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean "can I give a reference?" Milnor's Morse Theory (section 18 and 19) show the result. Thm. 19.2 (due to Cartan, "Lecons sur la Geometrie des Espaces de Riemann", Paris, 1926 and 1951) says "Suppose M is simply connected complete Riemannian manifold, and the sectional curvature is everywhere $\le 0$. THen two points of $M$ are joined by a unique geodesic. Furthermore $M$ is diffeomorphic to the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$.